# Коррекция данных в TextField

Tags: java, javafx

Мне требуется корректировать данные в некотором TextField непосредственно в процессе ввода. Чего конкретно я пытаюсь достичь:

- Ввод строго только чисел
- Числа должны быть [1; 500], и только в этом промежутке
- При удалении всех символов в поле автоматически записывается 1-ца, а при превышении числа 500 - записывается 500
- Ведущие нули автоматически урезаются(нельзя ввести ноль, или пример с числом "105", удаляем единицу - текст исправляется на просто "5").

Для этого я повесил обработчик на TextField и написал в него следующий код:

```
valueSliderStrokeWidth.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable,
                            String oldValue, String newValue) {
            System.out.println("edit text");
            String text = newValue;
            if(text.equals("")){
                valueSliderStrokeWidth.setText("1");
                return;
            }
            int num;
            try{
                num = Integer.parseInt(text);
                if(num == 0){
                    valueSliderStrokeWidth.setText("1");
                }else if(num > 500){
                    valueSliderStrokeWidth.setText("500");
                }else{
                    valueSliderStrokeWidth.setText(String.valueOf(num));
                }
            }catch(Exception ex){
                valueSliderStrokeWidth.setText(oldValue);
            }
        }
    });
```

Всё работает корректно, кроме одного, а именно, удаление ведущих нулей в процессе ввода. К примеру - пример с числом "105". Удаляя единицу я получаю следующую трассировку:

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The start must be <= the end  at
>   javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.getText(TextInputControl.java:446)
>     at
>   javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.updateContent(TextInputControl.java:564)
>     at
>   javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.replaceText(TextInputControl.java:548)
>     at
>   javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.deleteText(TextInputControl.java:496)
>     at
>   javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.deletePreviousChar(TextInputControl.java:899)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextFieldSkin.deleteChar(TextFieldSkin.java:589)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextFieldBehavior.deleteChar(TextFieldBehavior.java:198)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.deletePreviousChar(TextInputControlBehavior.java:311)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callAction(TextInputControlBehavior.java:143)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.callActionForEvent(BehaviorBase.java:218)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callActionForEvent(TextInputControlBehavior.java:127)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.lambda$new$74(BehaviorBase.java:135)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)  at
>   javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)  at
>   javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:3964)    at
>   javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3910)    at
>   javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2040)  at
>   javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2501)    at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:217)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:149)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$352(GlassViewEventHandler.java:248)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:247)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:546)  at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:966)    at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Подскажите, что и где я делаю неправильно, или более элегантное решение. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобраться в проблеме помогло [это.](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8081700)

Соответственно, код надо немного изменить так:

```
        valueSliderStrokeWidth.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable,
                            String oldValue, String newValue) {
            int num = 1;
            String text = newValue;
            if (!text.equals("")) {
                try {
                    num = Integer.parseInt(text);
                    if (num == 0) {
                        valueSliderStrokeWidth.setText("1");
                    } else if (num > 500) {
                        valueSliderStrokeWidth.setText("500");
                    } else {
                        final int n = num;
                        Platform.runLater(() -> {
                            valueSliderStrokeWidth.setText(String.valueOf(n));
                     valueSliderStrokeWidth.positionCaret(String.valueOf(n).length());         
                        });
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    valueSliderStrokeWidth.setText(oldValue);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```